# How to convert Proxy to Array in mobx-react

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react

I have an observable variable defined in the store, and I attempt to make multiple calls and push results to the Array. When I am so doing this, I find the array I defined is a proxy so that I cannot display the info in my page.
This is my attempt:

```
class ClubListStore {
  @observable userClubList

  constructor() {
    this.userClubList = []
  }


  @action getUserClubs = () => {
    const userContract = new appchain.base.Contract(playerAbi, config.userContract)
    appchain.base.getDefaultAccount().then(sender => {
      userContract.methods.getUserClubsSize(sender).call().then((res) => {
        return res
      }).then((res) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < res; i++) {
            userContract.methods.getUserClubs(sender, i).call().then((clubAddr) => {
              this.userClubList.push(clubAddr)//push value to array here
            })
          }
        }
      })
    })
  }


}

const clubListStore = new ClubListStore()

export default clubListStore
```

When I console.log the array userClubList, it is displayed as a proxy.

```
Proxy {0: "0xf3fA7DB0Cb79b12ca2081F9f5865f3fd01127FAd", length: 1, Symbol(mobx administration): ObservableArrayAdministration}
[[Handler]]
:
Object
[[Target]]
:
Array(1)
[[IsRevoked]]
:
false
```

My question is:
How can I convert this proxy to the array that holds values I pushed in from calls?

thank you

Comment: observable arrays are iterable so not sure why you would have problems displaying the data. Can call slice() or toJS() to get at actual array (from observable docs)

Answer (score 1):

use `console.log(toJS(userClubList))`

https://mobx.js.org/api.html#tojs

Answer (score 0):

use `Array.from()`

```
let proxyArray = new Proxy([1, 2, 3], {});
console.log(Array.form(proxyArray));//retrun array type
```